Fuzzy cluster analysis with binary and continue data
I am using R to conduct a fuzzy cluster analysis. I was told that the common fuzzy c means (which is similar to the k mean in the crisp cluster) is not suitable for mixed types of data.
I was wondering if I can generate a dissimilar matrix using Gower's coefficient, and then apply the matrix in c mean? or if there is any alternative available package in R that can be used to conduct fuzzy cluster analysis with mixed data ?
